# Install rcp on RHEL

Tags: rhel, software-installation, rsh

I have a Linux Red Hat machine version 6.4 (64-bit).

I notice that the `rcp` command does not exist on my machine (no `rcp` binary).
I also searched in Google in order to find an `rcp` binary that will fit for my Linux machine but with no success.

Where I can download `rcp`?

Comment: Is there a special reason not to use the secure `scp`? For non-interactive use you can generate a private/public keypair from the client (private-key) to host (public-key) machine that you want to communicate between.

Comment: on the remote machine I not have scp

Comment: is it possible to use scp on my machine while on target machine scp not exist?

Comment: You only need the `ssh-server` on the remote machine.

Comment: Hi Anthon see please my questions about "connection refused" for sharkbait

Comment: Is rshd running on the remote machine? Are you sure it allows connections from your client? What OS is the remote machine running, and what do you know about its configuration? Is there a firewall between the client and the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using CentOS 6.5 and rcp binary belongs to package `krb5-appl-clients-1.0.1-7.el6_2.1.x86_64`

```
[root@CentOS-VM1 6]# rpm -qf $(which rcp)
krb5-appl-servers-1.0.1-7.el6_2.1.x86_64
krb5-appl-clients-1.0.1-7.el6_2.1.x86_64
```

My CentOS version --

```
[root@CentOS-VM1 6]# lsb_release -d
Description:    CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

You can install package `krb5-appl-clients-1.0.1-7.el6_2.1.x86_64` using `yum`

```
yum install krb5-appl-clients
```

**Note**: I will recommend you to use `scp` or `rsync` over `ssh` (private/public authentication)

Comment: after I install the rcp by yum , what addtional steps I need to do in orderto use rcp , because rcp installed , but not copy the files - I get Connection refused

Answer (score 3):

You can try (as root), typing in

```
yum install rsh
```

It's probably not installed, since it's old and insecure, but you CAN install it and get it going.

RCP/RSH is old and insecure, and designing things to work with it, rather than updating to make use of more current technology, is pointless.

Maybe try showing the 'designer' [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169465&rll=1) or even better, show your mgr.

---

Now you can try these steps:

#### Step 01: Turn on RCP service on UNIX Host

Turn on the RCP service on unix machine by using `inetd`:

1. Log on as root.
2. Edit the file `/etc/inetd.conf`.
3. Uncomment the lines that start with `shell` and that start with `exec`.
4. Save the file.
5. Use `ps -ef | grep inetd` and determine `inetd` service pid. Send the Host User Profile (HUP) signal to `inetd` by using `kill` or by using `pkill`.
6. Run `inetd` again using `inetd restart`.

To turn on the RCP service by using `xinetd`:

1. Log on as root.
2. Edit the file `/etc/Xinetd.d/rsh`. You may get another file based on your Linux distribution.
3. Change the line disable to `no`.
4. Save the file.
5. Use `ps -ef | grep inetd` and determine `inetd` service pid. Send the HUP signal to `xinetd` by using `kill` or by using `pkill`.
6. Run `xinetd` again by using `xinetd restart` or `service xinetd restart`.

#### Step 02: Set the security permissions

After turning on RCP services, you must set the security permissions to allow the Windows host to connect to your computer.

1. Edit the file `/etc/hosts.equiv`. Based on your Linux distribution this file may vary. You can get like `/etc/hosts.allow`.
2. In the file add a line that contains the name of your Windows host.
3. Add a second line that contains the name of your Windows host and the name of a user, who can access the directory that you want to transfer. Separate the two elements with a tab character.
4. Save the file.

Comment: after I install the rcp by yum , what addtional steps I need to do in orderto use rcp , because rcp installed , but not copy the files - I get  Connection refused

Comment: Read my additions and try in this way. Tell me if this works!